# Isar : 'try' and everything else failed to proof these lemmas

Tags: isabelle, proof, isar

```
datatype alpha = a | b

inductive S :: "alpha list ⇒ bool" where
 empty [simp]: "S []" | 
 step1 [simp]: "S w ⟹ S (a # w @ [b])" |
 step2 [simp]: "⟦S w1; S w2⟧ ⟹ S (w1 @ w2)"

fun balanced :: "nat ⇒ alpha list ⇒ bool" where
 "balanced 0 [] = True "|
 "balanced n (a # w) = balanced (Suc n) w"  |
 "balanced (Suc n) (b # w) = balanced n w " |
 "balanced n w = False"
```

The function `balanced` is defined such that `balanced n w = S (replicate n a @ w)` 
where `replicate n a` returns list `[a,a,...,a]` of length n.
I have to prove `balanced n w ⟹ S (replicate n a @ w)` and `S (replicate n a @ w) ⟹ balanced n w` and am having trouble doing both.

For `balanced n w ⟹ S (replicate n a @ w)` I tried to proof as below.

```
  proof (induct n w rule : balanced.induct)
    case 1
    then show ?case by auto
  next
    case (2 n w)
    then show ?case by (metis Cons_eq_appendI ex5_7.b2 replicate_Suc replicate_app_Cons_same)
  next
    case (3 n w)
    then show ?case sorry
  next
    case ("4_1" v)
    then show ?case by auto
  next
    case ("4_2" va)
    then show ?case by auto
  qed
```

For the third case I get the subgoal  `(balanced n w ⟹ S (replicate n a @ w)) ⟹ balanced (Suc n) (b # w) ⟹ S (replicate (Suc n) a @ b # w)` and failed to proof it even with `try`. Assuming  `S (x @ y) ⟹ S (x @ [a,b] @ y)`will solve the problem but I could not find a way to proof it either. Are there any other way to proof it or is it possible to proof  `S (x @ y) ⟹ S (x @ [a,b] @ y)`?

For `S (replicate n a @ w) ⟹ balanced n w`  I tried to proof as below.

```
 proof (induct n w rule : balanced.induct)
   case 1
   then show ?case by simp
 next
   case (2 n w)
   then show ?case try
     by (metis Cons_eq_appendI ex5_7.b2 replicate_Suc replicate_app_Cons_same)
 next
   case (3 n w)
   then show ?case sorry 
 next
   case ("4_1" v)
   then show ?case sorry
 next
   case ("4_2" va)
   then show ?case sorry
 qed
```

The reason that I could not proof case 3, 4_1 and 4_2 is apparently because the assumptions of all 3 subgoals are always false. For example, the subgoal I got for case 4_2 is  `S (replicate 0 a @ b # va) ⟹ balanced 0 (b # va)`. Since `balanced 0 (b # va)` is always false. I will need to show that `S (replicate 0 a @ b # va)`is always false too. Is there a way to do this without changing the definition of `S`
?

Comment: At first glance, this looks like a pretty tough little problem. The trick is to figure out a solid pen-and-paper proof first. Without that, you won't be able to formalise anything in Isabelle. And with it, it should be quite doable.

Comment: @一十一 Whenever you ask a question about an exercise from a book, it is best to provide a reference. I believe that this is Exercise 5.7 from the book Concrete Semantics with Isabelle/HOL by T. Nipkow and G. Klein.